Have my array be split and added on to the new array, instead of completely restarting it each loop
I have a problem with my array. Each loop, the array gets cleared and new values gets added onto it. How could I make it so as the array gets filtered, it gets added to a new array to fill it up with new and filtered strings. The code essentially filters a text file that contains a food menu. It's supposed to take out the ':' from the text file, and remove all the empty array positions. I want this data to stay so when the second loop happens to filter the second line of the text file, it doesn't clear the filtered array, but should add onto it.
        public override void Select()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{MenuText()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in _reader.paths)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{i}. {file}");
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            int selectedIndex = ConsoleHelpers.GetIntegerInRange(1, _reader.paths.Count, MenuText()) - 1;
            string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(_reader.paths[selectedIndex]);
            if (result.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file - No data found");
            }
            else if (result.Length > 0) 
            {
                string[] splitArray;
                foreach (string file in result)
                {
                    splitArray = file.Split(':').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
                    splitArray = splitArray.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried adding a for loop in the foreach loop, however it didn't really fix it and instead created the same problem.

Can you please edit your question and add more details such as some sample input and the expected output?

I added a bit more information about what the expected output should be

Thanks for adding more details but it would still be helpful to see a sample input string and the expected output.

Need more information e.g. sample input text value

you can use 'list' for your splited file items then you can convert to array.
var splitedStringList = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (string file in result)
{
    var tmp = file.Split(':').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
    splitedStringList.Add(tmp.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList());
}


How could I convert it to an array? Also how could I be able to get a specific point in the array so I can print out to the console?
